# Website Homepage loses styling when SSL forced

Tags: wordpress, firefox, ssl, https

i recently had a SSL certificate installed on my website and all seems to be working ok. Except, when i try to force SSL on the homepage, the website breaks down completely. (its like the stylesheet is lost and the website goes crazy!)

This normally happens in firefox. Could anyone help?

Website is Verdacci.com

I don't really want to force SSL anywhere on the site except cart and checkout, but i want the website to be SSL compatible if for some reason it is forced.

The error i get from Firefox is about insecure content. I have made most of my content start with the HTTPS, but some content which is loaded by Wordpress (and therefore Wordpress should load the S) seems to be breaking the site maybe?

Comment: You need to make Wordpress load everything over SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you update the `home url` and `site url` from the settings of your wordpress site. then go to your  `functions.php` fine and add this on the top

```
function toz_force_https () {
  if ( !is_ssl() ) {
    wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
    exit();
  }
}
add_action ( 'template_redirect', 'toz_force_https', 1 );
```

Now go to your `wp-config.php` and aff the following after the starting of `<?php`

```
if ( $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "yoursite.com" ) {
    define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
    define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
}
```

Now to to the `.htaccess` file of yours and put this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

After this most of your ssl issue would be fixed, and it still you get the `http mixed content issue` that means `http` protocol has been hardcoded inside some link of your theme. Check your theme's `functions.php` again and search for `http://`. Most of the devs do not follow proper coding rules and henceforth add absolute protocol based url instead of using relative url. If you find any url like that `http://fonts.google.com/blah-bla` make it `//fonts.google.com/blah-bla` so that it will be protocol relative.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your CSS is being loaded over `http`. Is there any reason you don't want your whole site to be loaded over SSL? You're probably only losing about 40ms max to serve it over SSL and Google now uses SSL as a ranking factor.

However, if you only want to load certain pages over SSL you can use this filter:

```
function so27727003_ssl_pages( $force_ssl, $id = 0 ) {
    // A list of posts that should be SSL
    $ssl_posts = array(1, 12, 19);

    if(in_array($id, $ssl_posts)) {
        $force_ssl = true;
    }

    return $force_ssl;
}
add_filter( 'force_ssl' , 'so27727003_ssl_pages', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: how do i change the CSS to load over HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an `http://` somewhere in the WP database.

Check the siteurl, homeurl settings in WP admin-settings-general.

They should be updated to be `https://`

You may also need to update image paths and links in the database.
This can be done by backing up, then exporting the SQL database (through phpMyAdmin) then executing a find/replace command (http:/ => https://) and then deleting the database tables, and importing the new database.